# I have an issue with restarting my game called "Bounce"

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to programming. I started off with this book called "Python for kids". I wanna know how I can restart the game with a left mouse click. I really don't know how to program it. The book is very good for me to learn python but I need some more extra information.

Can you guys help me?

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time


class Bal:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, score, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.score = score
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.hit_bottom = False


    def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
               self.score.hit()
               return True 
        return False

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos [1] <= 0:
            self.y = 3
        if pos [3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.hit_bottom = True
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3
        if pos [0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos [2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3


class paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.started = False
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<Button-1>', self.start_game)




    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0

    def turn_left(self, evt):
        self.x = -3

    def start_game(self, evt):
        self.started = True


    def turn_right(self, evt):
        self.x = 3

class score:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.score = 0
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_text(450,20, text=self.score,font=("Times", 20), fill=color)

    def hit(self):
        self.score += 1
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.id, text=self.score)



tk = Tk()
tk.title("bouncespel made by Robel Tewolde")
tk.resizable(0,0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.configure(background='black')
canvas.pack()
tk.update()


score = score(canvas, 'red')    
paddle = paddle(canvas, 'White')
bal = Bal(canvas, paddle, score,'red')
spel_over = canvas.create_text(250, 200,font="Times", text='HET SPEL IS AFGELOPEN', state='hidden')



while 1:
    if bal.hit_bottom == False and paddle.started == True:
        bal.draw()
        paddle.draw()
    if bal.hit_bottom == True:
        time.sleep(2)
        canvas.itemconfig(spel_over, state='normal')
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update() 
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to reset all the variables to initial state to restart.
I have added a restart method which first stops the paddle, destroys the ball, resets the score and initializes the ball to the start position. Also find corresponding methods in the classes.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time


class Bal:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, score, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.score = score
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 100)
        starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.hit_bottom = False

    def restart(self, canvas, paddle, score, color):
        self.__init__(canvas, paddle, score, color)

    def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
               self.score.hit()
               return True 
        return False

    def destroy(self):
        self.canvas.delete(self.id)

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos [1] <= 0:
            self.y = 3
        if pos [3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.hit_bottom = True
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3
        if pos [0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos [2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3


class paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.started = False
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<Button-1>', self.start_game)

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0

    def turn_left(self, evt):
        self.x = -3

    def start_game(self, evt):
        self.started = True

    def stop(self):
        self.started = False

    def turn_right(self, evt):
        self.x = 3

class score:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.score = 0
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_text(450,20, text=self.score,font=("Times", 20), fill=color)

    def hit(self):
        self.score += 1
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.id, text=self.score)

    def reset_score(self):
        self.score = 0



tk = Tk()
tk.title("bouncespel made by Robel Tewolde")
tk.resizable(0,0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.configure(background='black')
canvas.pack()
tk.update()


score = score(canvas, 'red')    
paddle = paddle(canvas, 'White')
bal = Bal(canvas, paddle, score,'red')


def restart():
    bal.destroy()
    paddle.stop()
    score.reset_score()
    bal.restart(canvas, paddle, score, 'red')


spel_over = canvas.create_text(400, 200,font="Times", text='HET SPEL IS AFGELOPEN', state='hidden')


def quit(event):                           
        print("Double Click, so let's stop") 
        import sys; sys.exit() 


while 1:
    if bal.hit_bottom == False and paddle.started == True:
        bal.draw()
        paddle.draw()
    if bal.hit_bottom == True:
        restart()
        canvas.itemconfig(spel_over, state='normal')
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update() 
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: Dear Mister Reck,
thank you for your time and for your answer.
This has helped me a lot.
i am going to add more functions to my little game.